# Merging two PDFs

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, pdf-generation, pypdf

```
import PyPDF2 
import glob
import os
from fpdf import FPDF
import shutil

class MyPDF(FPDF): # adding a footer, containing the page number
    def footer (self):
        self.set_y(-15)
        self.set_font("Arial", Style="I", size=8)
        pageNum = "page %s/{nb}" % self.page_no()
        self.cell(0,10, pageNum, align="C")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.chdir("pathtolocation/docs/") # docs location
    os.system("libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf *") # this converts everything to pdf
    for file in glob.glob("*"):
        if file not in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
            shutil.move(file,"/newlocation") # moving files we don't need to another folder

    # adding the cover and footer
    path = open(file, 'wb')
    path2 = open ('/pathtocover/cover.pdf')
    merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
    pdf = MyPDF()

    for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
        pdf.footer()
        merger.merge(position=0, fileobj=path2)
        merger.merge(position=0, fileobj=path)
        merger.write(open(file, 'wb'))
```

This script converts to pdf, add a cover to the pdf and footer containing the page number, fixed some stuff and now I run it for the last time to see if it's working, it's taking too much time, no error, did I do something wrong or does it need that long to merge and add footers? I'm working with 3 files, and it converted them so fast.

Exception output

```
convert /home/projects/convert-pdf/docs/sample (1).doc ->
/home/projects/convert-pdf/docs/sample (1).pdf using writer_pdf_Export
```

so it is converting and moving, I think the problem is somewhere here

```
   for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
        pdf.footer()
        merger.merge(position=0, fileobj=path2)
        merger.merge(position=0, fileobj=path)
        merger.write(open(file, 'wb'))
```

Since I'm trying to merge `position=0` with `position=0`, not sure about it though

Comment: Try throwing some intermediate ```print``` statements in there to see exactly where its hanging

Comment: @wnnmaw my initial thought was at the very end but it's not even converting the files, i mean previously there were errors but it passed the stage of converting and moving but not now

Comment: @picus i'll do that now

Comment: I just moved to the answer section to show some samples, don't copy and paste, formatting might get messed up.

Comment: @wnnmaw please read my edit

Comment: Save the PDFs to disk and use pdftk using the following command. `pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf cat output newfile.pdf`. Make sure pdftk is installed on your system. Edit: You could also use `pdftk *.pdf cat output newfile.pdf`

Comment: @12hys can I add a footer using that tool too?

Comment: @Fischer, I don't believe it does. Are you able to successfully add the footers to the separate PDFs? If so, save the PDFs and use pdftk on the saved files. I would first check to see what is actually taking a really long time. Is it adding the footers or merging? Comment out the merger code to see if that's what is causing the slowdown.

Comment: @12hys  the error is definitely from the adding footer section

Answer (score 4):

This is actually better as a comment, but I want to show code. You need to add some try blocks in there to catch any errors - here is something super basic you coudld do.

```
import PyPDF2 
import glob
import os
from fpdf import FPDF
import shutil

class MyPDF(FPDF): # adding a footer, containing the page number
    def footer (self):
      try:
        self.set_y(-15)
        self.set_font("Arial", Style="I", size=8)
        pageNum = "page %s/{nb}" % self.page_no()
        self.cell(0,10, pageNum, align="C")
      except Exception, err:
        print "Error applying footer: {}".format(err)


if __name__ == "__main__":

  try:
    os.chdir("pathtolocation/docs/") # docs location
    os.system("libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf *") # this converts everything to pdf
    for file in glob.glob("*"):
        if file not in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
            shutil.move(file,"/newlocation") # moving files we don't need to another folder

    # adding the cover and footer
    path = open(file, 'wb')
    path2 = open ('/pathtocover/cover.pdf')
    merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
    pdf = MyPDF()
  except Exception, err:
    print "error setting up the pdf: {}".format(err)

    for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
      try:
        pdf.footer()
        merger.merge(position=0, fileobj=path2)
        merger.merge(position=0, fileobj=path)
        merger.write(open(file, 'wb'))
      except Exception, err:
        print "Error processing glob: {}".format(err)
```

Comment: thank you for writing the exceptions, you didn't have to, still don't get errors but at least i know that it past the  conversion point and it moved the files